# Missing Constraint Autolayout Warning

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a project and I used to add constraints with xcode interface builder. In a specific case I needed to add some constraints in my controllers source. My question is that although I have the result I was seeking for, xcode returns missing constraints warnings.

Is this something I should handle? I mean, I add constraints in the source code. Show I do something to update my storyboard in order to be aware of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to handle these, but if you want to get rid of the warnings, you can add placeholder constraints in IB, that are removed at build time, so you can replace them with code generated constraints. When you select a constraint, and go to the Attributes Inspector, you will see a box, "Placeholder -- Remove at build time". If you check that box, those constraints are automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

No,you dont need to , if you have added constraints in the source code than it will be executed during runtime. so you dont need to handle those warning only if you have added those constraints in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

AutoLayout is a descriptive "language" which describes how the layout should be rendered (frames size, spacing etc.) into the view during the runtime. When you have missing constraints warning, in other words ambiguous layout,there is a good chance that the layout will have unpredictable behavior. In order to make sure that your layout is rendered as you wish, you should clear these warnings.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. I have missing constraints warnings but all of them are handled in source code. If I could force xcode take into consideration constraints created in source code then this "ambiguity" would vanish. Is there still a problem, or maybe something I don't understand?

Comment: No you still have ambiguity, as the constraints in the interface builder and the constraints in source code are not applied in the same time (thing of the UIViewController Lifecycle). My opinion is either add the missing constraints in interface builder or add all the constraints into your source code.